# Automated testing chrome bluetooth api

Tags: web-bluetooth

Has anyone done automated testing with selenium (or any other framework) for their webapps that utilize the chrome bluetooth api? I've seen people use adb to facilitate but i would love to be able to simulate a device connection in code.

Answer (score 0):

Consider replacing the browser implementation with a testing implementation of the API.